# How to get the log-denisty from pymc3 model?

Tags: probability-density, pymc3

I have drawn samples from a simple model using pymc3:

```
import pymc3 as pm

with pm.Model() as model:
    var_x = pm.Normal(name='var_x', mu = 0, sd = 1)
    trace = pm.sample(10)

print(trace['var_x'])
```

I wonder if `trace` contains the values of the log-density (pm.Normal) for each value in `trace['var_x']` and how to extract it.

If `trace` does not retain the log-density, is there any other possibility to get the values by using pymc3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can recompute it by doing

```py
[var_x.logp(i) for i in trace]
```

or more general

```py
[[free.logp(i) for i in trace] for free in model.free_RVs]]
```

You may also want to check how similar expressions are used in PyMC3 to compute information criteria [stats](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/stats.py)

Comment: Many thanks aloctavodia! Your answer worked properly.